# Filter method - Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use method filter in Angular.JS and take first element with name Games

```
$scope.example = [
        {model : "Games", id : "1"},
        {model : "Pictures", id : "2"},
        {model : "Cars", id : "3"},
        {model : "Games", id : "4"},
    ];
```

in HTML is very easy take this but in JS I don`t know how :(

```
$scope.example.filter(model:Games).TakeFirst()???
```

Comment: Create custom filter which will return `return arr.find(o => o.model === name);`

Comment: @Tushar Yes it`s working correct - give this as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use filters in your controller you should inject `$filter`. After that, you can get first element using `[0]`.

Example;

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.example = [
        {model : "Games", id : "1"},
        {model : "Pictures", id : "2"},
        {model : "Cars", id : "3"},
        {model : "Games", id : "4"},
    ];
    console.log( $filter('filter')($scope.example, { model: "Games" })[0]);
});
```